# Working with arrays: extracting an array from an array with a simple condition

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$quizzes = array();
            $Quiz = array(
                'quiz_id'   => $quiz_id,
                'correct'   => $correctAnswers
            );
            $quizzes[] = $Quiz;
```

`$quizzes` is an array which contains many quizzes called `Quiz`, which in turn have `$Quiz['quiz_id'] and $Quiz['correct']`.  Now what I'm trying to do is to **select a particular quiz from the list** of quizzes in `$quizzes` where quiz_id=1.

If such quiz exists, I would like to echo quiz is found. If no $Quiz with such id exists, echo no quiz is found.

A simple solution that I came up with is to do a foreach loop.

```
foreach($quizzes as $Quiz) if($Quiz['quiz_id'] == 1) {} else {}
```

However, since I have more than 1 quiz, it returns the else statement as many times as there are `$Quiz['quiz_id'] != 1` which is many many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexing your array such as `$quizzes[ $quiz_id ] = $Quiz;` would permit you to go straight to that item in the array.

So take your existing line of

```
$quizzes[] = $Quiz;
```

and change it to

```
$quizzes[ $quiz_id ] = $Quiz;
```

then you can use

```
if( isset( $quizzes[ $quiz_id ] ) )
{
  echo 'found the quiz!';
}
else
{
  echo 'no quiz found';
}
```

where `$quiz_id` is the id of the quiz you wish to locate

Comment: But the thing is that $quizzes[1] corresponds to some $Quiz, which does not necessarily have quiz_id of 1?

Comment: Or let's say $quizzes[0] is the first ever $Quiz entered. If a user completed  5th test first, I would add $Quiz into this array where quiz_id=5. Then if $quizzes[5] doesn't yet exists, but there is a quiz with quiz_id 5

Comment: I think I see what you mean, you are indexing the positions of these quizzes based on id, so an array can be empty for the first 100 point $quizzess[0 to 99] but have $quizzes[100] as the first one if the user completes 100th quiz

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = 1;
array_filter($quizzes, function($v) use($id) {return $v['quid_id'] == $id;});
```